# how can i rotate my object in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

i rotate my object, that is a triangle . But my object's center moves.

```
      //background draw
DrawScreen();
glPushMatrix();

glTranslatef(xgotur,ygotur,zgotur);
glRotatef(derece,0.0,0.0,1.0);

      // drawing my object
glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glColor3d(0.2, 0.5, 0.7);
    glVertex2f(-0.1+aralik_bosluk, 0.0+aralik_bosluk);
    glVertex2f(0.0+aralik_bosluk,0.4+aralik_bosluk);
    glVertex2f(0.1+aralik_bosluk, 0.0+aralik_bosluk);
glEnd();    
      // finish draw
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Just a note: It is hard to understand the meaning of variable names when they are not in english. For the sake of internationalism you should consider using english variable names.

Comment: thank u for ur answer but i did it ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you rotate an object with `glRotate()`, it will rotate around the World Origin and not the origin of your object.

You should check a good example here about how to rotate your object around a Local Origin : 
[Rotation Local Origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977737/opengl-rotations-around-world-origin-when-they-should-be-around-local-origin)